# tekton & buildpack: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: buildpack, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I've deployed a local docker registry. It uses a self-signed certificate.

When I'm trying to run buildpacks task, I'm getting this message:

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I've took a look on documentation, about how to add my docker registry certificate, but I've not been able to set it up.

`pipeline.yaml` is:

```yaml
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Pipeline
metadata:
  name: build-and-deploy-pipeline
spec:
  workspaces:
    - name: git-source
      description: The git repo
    - name: dockerconfig-ws
      description: Docker configuration
  params:
    - name: gitUrl
      description: Git repository url
  tasks:
    - name: fetch-repository
      taskRef:
        name: git-clone
      workspaces:
        - name: output
          workspace: git-source
      params:
        - name: url
          value: "$(params.gitUrl)"
        - name: subdirectory
          value: "."
        - name: deleteExisting
          value: "true"
    - name: buildpacks
      taskRef:
        name: buildpacks
      runAfter:
        - fetch-repository
      workspaces:
        - name: source
          workspace: git-source
        - name: dockerconfig
          workspace: dockerconfig-ws
      params:
        - name: APP_IMAGE
          value: host.k3d.internal:5443/restservice
        - name: BUILDER_IMAGE
          value: paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny
```

And `pipelinerun.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  generateName: tekton101lab-pipelinerun-
spec:
  pipelineRef:
    name: build-and-deploy-pipeline
  params:
    - name: gitUrl
      value: https://xxx@gitlab.com/cicdgitops/rest-service.git/
  workspaces:
    - name: git-source
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: git-pvc
    - name: cache-ws
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: cache-pvc
    - name: dockerconfig-ws
      secret:
        secretName: dockerconfig-secret
```

Any ideas?

I mean, how could I add my docker registry certificate as a trusted ca certificate?

You can see behavior [here](https://asciinema.org/a/eKTTnwuF7wVUzQJKsYDhXF9Fc). Problem arises when buildpacks tasks are trying to reach my docker registry (`host.k3d.internal`).

Comment: "I've took a look on documentation, about how to add my docker registry certificate". Could you point to and explain what you've tried?

Comment: I took a look at [here](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/install/#configuring-self-signed-cert-for-private-registry)

Comment: Where do you get this "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" from? Are you certain this is related to your registry -- rather than, say, a client querying gitlab.com, while its trusted CAs is outdated? Though the registry is way more likely to be this issue, for sure ... Still we have no idea how you came to see your error. Please elaborate.

Comment: Wild-guessing: your Kubernetes hosts container runtime should be configured trusting your self-signed registry certificate. By default, cri-o/docker/containerd/rkt/.... all runtimes I know of would refuse to pull from self-signed registries, until you setup an exception (or better: trust the missing CA). Leaving tekton aside: first make sure you can start containers that pull images out of your registry.

Comment: You can see behavior [here](https://asciinema.org/a/eKTTnwuF7wVUzQJKsYDhXF9Fc). Problem arises when buildpacks is trying to check if requested image already exist. By other hand, how could I add this CA certificate into kubernetes?